# gunzip and mysql import - No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, bash, gunzip

I have created a bash script for the automation of my database restore. When I run the following commands, I get /my/sql/file/path.sql: No such file or directory.

```
ssh $USER@"$cloneMysqlHost" gunzip /path/file.sql.gz && MySQL -u root -p db_name < /path/file.sql
```

I did an ls -lrot on the host I ssh to, just to make sure the file exists the permissions are correct, and they are.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your intent is unclear because of the `&&` and `<`, which are probably not doing what you expect they are. Where exactly are the files in question (local and remote), and where is mysql supposed to be running?

Comment: Have you tried putting "" around the commands to be executed on the remote host?  Something like "gunzip /path/file.sql.gz && MySQL -u root -p db_name < /path/file.sql" so you get more than the gunzip executed there.

Comment: i doubt that there is a command named "MySQL". *nix systems are case sensitive so you should probably use `mysql` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The `&&` is causing the *local* shell to split the command and run the `MySQL` command locally.

The `<` redirection is also being done locally (and the cause of your error).

The `gunzip` is being performed on the remote host though.

You need to quote the **entire** argument to `ssh` if you want it all run on the remote system.

```
ssh "$USER@$cloneMysqlHost" 'gunzip /path/file.sql.gz && MySQL -u root -p db_name < /path/file.sql'
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I wasn't aware that anything after the && would be done locally. This worked liked a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Are you providing the password properly? Also, not sure what's going on with the &&, should use a pipe there. MySql is probably not valid, use mysql. See [here](http://webcheatsheet.com/sql/mysql_backup_restore.php) for more details.

```
ssh $USER@"$cloneMysqlHost" gunzip /path/file.sql.gz | mysql -u root -p [password] db_name
```

Comment: A pipe is incorrect here. `gunzip` is not sending data to standard output (though it could be changed to do that and avoid the "temporary" file).

Comment: @EtanReisner Ah, right you are. Your answer looks correct.